# Run web application from local machine and host files on external server

Tags: mysql, django, web-services, apache, mamp

**ReWrite of same Question**

I'm building a web application using Django. I have a web server that holds my static files, but that is all it can do. I want to run the website from my computer using MAMP. On my system I have a MySql database. How do I tell django to fetch my static files from  server and serve them to the user?

Currently another computer (in my network) can go to my site and request pages. MAMP receives it but fetches the files from my local directory on my HD. I want to set it so that it will only fetch files from the origin server.

INFO on what I'm using:

MAMP, MySql, Apache, Django

Thanks

Comment: Can you be more specific, where will apache be and where will mysql be and where will the webpages be? I think I know what you are saying but please clarify.

Comment: Try again. You're still not making any sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, just change the `STATIC_URL` in the `settings.py` to the server the holds the static files:

in settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = 'http://staticserver/path/to/static/on/apache'
```

(make sure the change media_url as well if needed)